# How can I include a Swift file which is in a different Group?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a structure like this:

[image: A file tree with the root and a single subdirectory named "Views". In Views are two files named DropDownPlayView.xib and SlidePlayView.xib, respectively. In the root directory is one file named AppDelegate.swift.]

My question is simple. **How can I create variables of type `SlidePlayView` within `AppDelegate`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if the SlidePlayView.xib contains a view, but if it does, the following should work if the xib contains the correct view as its first object:

```
let slidePlayView  = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SlidePlayView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as SlidePlayView
```

Comment: That would only give you a reference to a UINib, not the underlying UIView.

Comment: Yes you would have to instantiate view form the nib